# How to enable large file support under Darwin?

Tags: c, linux, fopen, darwin, large-file-support

I have a C application I am trying to compile for Mac OS X 10.6.4:

```
$ uname -v
Darwin Kernel Version 10.4.0: Fri Apr 23 18:28:53 PDT 2010; root:xnu-1504.7.4~1/RELEASE_I386
```

My `gcc` is as follows:

```
$ gcc --version
i686-apple-darwin10-gcc-4.2.1 (GCC) 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5664)
```

My `Makefile` is as follows:

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -O3 -Wformat -Wall -pedantic -std=gnu99

all: myApp
    rm -rf *~

myApp: myApp.o
    ${CC} ${CFLAGS} myApp.o -lbz2 -o myApp
    rm -rf *~

clean:
    rm -rf *.o myApp
```

The issue is that my application makes calls to `fseeko64` and `fopen64`, and uses the `off64_t` type for offsets. When I compile my application I get the following warnings and errors:

```
$ make myApp
gcc -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -O3 -Wformat -Wall -pedantic -std=gnu99   -c -o myApp.o myApp.c
myApp.c: In function ‘extractData’:
myApp.c:119: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘fseeko64’
myApp.c:119: error: ‘off64_t’ undeclared (first use in this function)
myApp.c:119: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
myApp.c:119: error: for each function it appears in.)
myApp.c: In function ‘extractMetadata’:
myApp.c:305: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘fopen64’
myApp.c:305: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast
```

My code builds without errors under Linux. What changes can I make to the source code to add large file support when building under Darwin?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

On Darwin file I/O is 64-bit by default (10.5 at least), just found this by grepping in /usr/include:

```
sys/_types.h:typedef __int64_t  __darwin_off_t;

unistd.h:typedef __darwin_off_t     off_t;
```

So all you need to do is something like

```
#ifdef __APPLE__
#  define off64_t off_t
#  define fopen64 fopen
...
#endif
```

Comment: @AlexReynolds I wouldn't call it perfect, see my answer.

Answer (score 7):

While this question has an up-voted accepted answer which works I think the solution is a bit misleading. Instead of fixing something *it's always better to avoid having to fix it later in the first place*.

For example for the `fopen64` function the [GNU C Library](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/libc/manual/html_node/Opening-Streams.html) docs say:

> If the sources are compiled with `_FILE_OFFSET_BITS == 64` on a 32 bits machine **this function is available under the name `fopen` and so transparently replaces the old interface**.

You can just use the same function `fopen` on systems that support 64-bit I/O by default and you can set the `_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64` flag on 32-bit without the need write redefines at all. The same goes for types like `off64_t` vs. `off_t`.

Save the redefines for the case when you have to deal with 3rd party sources and use standard functions in your own code.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. This is the right way to fix this.

Comment: I looked into this more and although this should be the accepted answer for non-Darwin platforms, on Darwin they have made the file functions 64-bit, and `_FILE_OFFSET_BITS` and `_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE` don't exist. So the accepted answer is probably the best way to fix such a portability issue.

Answer (score 1):

The fseeko and similar commands work with large file support so no need for the fseeko64 etc [Apple man page](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/fseeko.3.html)